# Django - authenticate() return None

Tags: python, django, authentication, nonetype

I read many of topic about this problem and the problem is always there. When I submit my login form, the authenticate function() returns None. I used the function set_password() for the registration and it changes nothing.

Here is my code (also [here](https://repl.it/CbTW/0)):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render
from forms import LoginForm, RegistrationForm
from django.contrib import auth

def login(request):
    state = 0 # 0 = initialisation / 1 = OK / 2 = BAD_PW
    form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        error = False
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = LoginForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                email = form.cleaned_data["email"]
                password = form.cleaned_data["password"]
                user = auth.authenticate(email=email,
                                    password=password)
                if user:
                    auth.login(request, user)
                    state = 1
                else:
                    state = 2
                    print "login state " + str(state)
        else:
            form = LoginForm()

    return render(request, "birneo/login.html", locals())

def register(request):
    state = 0
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User()
            user.username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            user.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
            user.save()
            state = 1
            form = RegistrationForm()
        else:
            form = RegistrationForm()

    return render(request, "birneo/register.html", locals())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you try to authenticate user against the email / password pair and there is no backend that accepts such a pair. The model backend accepts username / password pair, so to authenticate with email use:

```
(...)
if form.is_valid():
    email = form.cleaned_data["email"]
    password = form.cleaned_data["password"]
    username = User.objects.get(email=email).username
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user:
(...)
```